# My numeric sheet name not found Range when use pure get Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I also have sheet name ..."4"... as a number

But it shows error as "Exception: Range not found"

I think because my sheet name is a number, but I really need the sheet name as a number

I try this, it should work. but it turns out, it's not

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var shname = ss.getRange("Home!A1") // A1 contains value 4 as a number

  ss.getRange("'" + shname + "'!A1").setValue("is it worked?") // how to fix this line?
```

for fully info 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GcyfutUP-vg23H9mpjfNLRQvTkOqp0c8dN-J4R8g9Hk/edit#gid=1502470412&range=A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the range/cell. Change the second line in the script to

```
var shname = ss.getRange("Home!A1").getDisplayValue() //getValue() should also work
```

and see if that works?

Comment: How come that I missed the basic one. "getValue" I also know more "getDisplayValue" Thanks a lot!